# Нужно ли ставить тире в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Выношу еще один вопрос на обсуждение. Нужно ли в предложении "Да пропади они пропадом, твои хрустальные мечты,(-)только бы чаще бились стаканы" ставить тире? И также обязателен ли воскл. знак или можно обойтись точкой (я понимаю, что предложение побудительное).

Comment: @Alenka, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно предложить  следующее оформление: "Да пропади они пропадом, твои хрустальные мечты, - только бы чаще бились стаканы!"

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Это БСП  фразеологизированной  структуры со следственно-условным значением. Постановка тире или запятой зависит дополнительных средств связи (наличия частиц, особых форм глагола), проясняющих  смысловые отношения между предложениями,  а также от структуры предложений, например:  «Даже в этой ситуации он пошел на все уступки ― только бы матч состоялся».  «Ужин не нужен, был бы обед» (посл.).

2) Тире факультативное, соответствует силе выражаемого чувства.

ПРИМЕРЫ

Она готова всё признать, покаяться во всем плохом, что ей приписывают близкие, ― только бы он был жив! (Василий Гроссман).

А по-моему: делай, что хочешь, только бы шито да крыто было (А. Н. Островский).

Пускай накажут, только бы не нынче, когда у нас гости (Л. Н. Толстой).

Да пусть бы она вообще ничего не готовила, он согласен был есть одни бутерброды хоть всю жизнь, только бы Сона не замирала вот так на краешке стула, опустив плечи, как подбитая птица! (Анна Берсенева).

Comment: Да, а зачем перед тире запятая? Вот, например, в таком предложении: "Ночью, когда теряются краски и предметы становятся серыми и размытыми, королева приходит в свою потайную комнату – и начинается колдовство". Запятая ведь не ставится, хотя это предложение тоже сложное.

Comment: также и здесь есть про постановку запятой перед тире: http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm
И по-моему этого случая здесь нет...

Comment: Запятая закрывает обособленное приложение, отнесенное к местоимению, тире ставится в БСП, постановка знаков препинания независимая.

Answer (score 2):

Да, тире возможно. Но возможно и так: Да пропади они пропадом, твои хрустальные мечты!Только бы чаще бились стаканы! Вторая часть является присоединительной конструкцией, которую можно выделить  тире. Но можно также оформить как отдельное предложение. Т.н. ***парцелляция***.

Дополнение

В вашем примере тире передает неожиданное присоединение: <...>и начинается колдовство.[Грамота.ру](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=419.EJHy_Qoqfylu0sWo-gBpaSgEqZuDF4mb80LkbOLoWDpo13M4mWn_1yxbPsdoetUl.ff0d9a3676b741513445a6fc9457498debe9c6b7&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9Xti-b8lArfpY2fz6fP4kJz3523BIyRaKdBrJ-E3tDYkBsxK1F7VLf7D1FaOsedkuunmAHGrF4JOmuOimE5VM15HccAgqb4x146NSQD_llNc3Crt-D77R4BfNQT9k6vRAIzE-DiuiGcqRrAcZL-LcVsUr8HSfuAR9Q8KUwomHpXS0Yj-vGWa-PDG&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxclhUVzM1eE1wbjBEZktJbU8ybXhCM3hINFFfRkxMVjRDeWxFblpCb3hxNnZiNUxCVHFOem5CbTAzQmFqTGZNTEVFNVNfeUJ5MllJZ3Izekt0eXRlc3NSMFRDRlU4ZFg5X2ZYaEp0Uk45ZENJNnJhSmRyVHlEOA&b64e=2&sign=04b272bd74883726d42f52a300dd7b78&keyno=0&l10n=ru&cts=1408303911803&mc=3.9069527926125205)